# Prevent overwriting createdAt and updatedAt in Cloud Function when object set includes them

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm writing some Node.js code to import data from an existing database into Firebase Cloud Firestore. We have createdAt and updatedAt dates that I want preserved in the transition. The problem is we've created Cloud Functions to automatically set those on object creation, thus it's always overwriting the object's value with the current timestamp. If I run our import script again, thus set is updating the existing document, the createdAt and updatedAt values in the object are preserved.

How can I make it use the specified values and not overwrite them with the current timestamp on create?

```
const oldNote = {
  id: "someid",
  text: "sometext",
  createdAt: new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 30, 0),
  updatedAt: new Date(2018, 11, 24, 10, 33, 30, 0)
}

const note = {
  text: oldNote.text,
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(oldNote.createdAt),
  updatedAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(oldNote.updatedAt)
};
firestoredb.collection("notes").doc(oldNote.id).set(note).then((docRef) => {
    //FIXME: createdAt and updatedAt aren't preserved, always today
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error setting user: ", error);
});
```

Here's the Cloud Functions:

```
exports.updateCreatedAt = functions.firestore
.document("{collectionName}/{id}")
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const now = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

    return snap.ref.set(
        {
            createdAt: now,
            updatedAt: now
        },
        { merge: true }
    );
});

exports.updateUpdatedAt = functions.firestore
.document("{collectionName}/{id}")
.onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data();
    const previousValue = change.before.data();

    if (
        Boolean(newValue.updatedAt) &&
        Boolean(previousValue.updatedAt) &&
        newValue.updatedAt.isEqual(previousValue.updatedAt)
    ) {
        const now = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

        return change.after.ref.set({ updatedAt: now }, { merge: true });
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly is `dateobj`?  Please spare no details. We should be able to take your code and run it for ourselves.

Comment: @DougStevenson It's a JavaScript date object. This is just an example, the old note is queried from a different database.

Comment: The exact values matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and deployed an update to the `onCreate` trigger in the Google Cloud Console. It now checks if the object already contains createdAt and/or updatedAt and uses them instead of overwriting them if so.

```
exports.updateCreatedAt = functions.firestore
.document("{collectionName}/{id}")
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
    const now = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    const createdAt = snap.data().createdAt != undefined ? snap.data().createdAt : now;
    const updatedAt = snap.data().updatedAt != undefined ? snap.data().updatedAt : now;

    return snap.ref.set(
        {
            createdAt: createdAt,
            updatedAt: updatedAt
        },
        { merge: true }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the API documentation for [Timestamp.fromDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#static-fromdate) takes a Date object and converts it to a Timestamp object.  However, you're passing it a Timestamp object (unless your edit is faking values that didn't come from the database write in Cloud Functions).  This is an unnecessary conversion, and it's likely just returning the current time instead of what you expect.  Just use the timestamp values in place:

```
const note = {
  text: oldNote.text,
  createdAt: oldNote.createdAt,
  updatedAt: oldNote.updatedAt
};
```

Bear in mind that when you write a Date into Firestore, it stores a Timestamp internally.  It's not going to come back out as a Date.

Comment: oldNote's created/updatedAt is a JavaScript date object, not a firebase.firestore.Timestamp.

Comment: Well, what you wrote in the Cloud Function is going to store a Timestamp.

Comment: That's desired. New note should have timestamps.

Comment: Yeah, so, as I said here, there's no need to convert if you're pulling a
 Timestamp out of the document using oldNote.

Comment: The documentation shows it the same way I'm doing it here: `dateExample: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date('December 10, 1815')),`

Comment: If you think there's a bug in the way fromDate works, I recommend sending your reproduction steps to the appropriate platform SDK on GitHub.  For the web client SDK, that would be https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/firestore

Comment: I don’t, that code is working correctly. The issue lies in our cloud function.

Comment: I can't see everything that's going on with your function.  I think you might have to take another pass at editing the question to be clear about what your function's input data is, what you expect it to do, and how that's different than what you expect.  Use logging and screenshots liberally.